# Not importing .usage files when they exist and are current

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, timer-jobs, web-analytics, usage-counters

In the ULS logs I found this error which occurs at 2:00 AM:

> There are no usage log files available to import with filter 'SV-SP-????????-?????.usage'

I did not notice this before because I was sorting by WebAnalytics.exe but I checked the usual suspects posted on blogs and forums (ex. Service started, service accounts, permissions, etc.)

.usage files are being created and seem to be updated regularly. Ex. it's 11:03 and the last modified time was around 10:30.

Comment: Is you web analytic. working? what is time zone settings on the server?

Comment: It is not working. Been trying different things. I realized that error may just be no usage files to import at that current moment since this is a timer job. Is that correct? 

** I have tried other possible fixes to hopefully to get this finally working

Answer (score 1):

The timer job was increased to 10 minutes so at times there were no USAGE files being generated.